# SVGPointList length changes using svg.js

Tags: gsap, svg.js

Hi I am using the function `createPoint` to animate a polygon using gsap. I am also using svg.js

If I use vanilla javascript to get the points of the svg with

```
var polygon = document.querySelector("polygon");
var points = polygon.points;
```

it returns 3 points which correspond to the number of times the `createPoint` function is run. This logs out as:

```
0: SVGPoint {x: 105.30396270751953, y: 143.0928955078125}
1: SVGPoint {x: 348.09027099609375, y: 97.7249984741211}
2: SVGPoint {x: 276.54010009765625, y: 327.56372070}
```

If I use the svg.js code

```
const draw = SVG().addTo('body')
var svg = draw.node;
const polygon = draw.polygon().node;
var points = polygon.points;
```

the same function logs a list of 4 SVGPoints with the first point being {x:0,y:0} even though I am only running the function 3 times. Where is the additional (index 0) svg point coming from? Thanks in advance

```
0: SVGPoint {x: 0, y: 0}
1: SVGPoint {x: 93.79865264892578, y: 124.19292449951172}
2: SVGPoint {x: 346.3572082519531, y: 97.5942153930664}
3: SVGPoint {x: 227.08517456054688, y: 269.97042846
```

given the following html

```
<svg>
<polygon points="">
</svg>
```

And the code below

```
TweenLite.defaultEase = Sine.easeInOut;
const draw = SVG().addTo('body')
var svg = draw.node;
const polygon = draw.polygon().node;
var points = polygon.points;
console.log('points',points)
var offset = 75;

createPoint(100, 100);
createPoint(300, 100);
createPoint(300, 300);
// createPoint(100, 300);

function createPoint(x, y) {
  
  var minX = x - offset;
  var maxX = x + offset;
  var minY = y - offset;
  var maxY = y + offset;
  
  var point = points.appendItem(svg.createSVGPoint());
  point.x = x;
  point.y = y;
  
  moveX();
  moveY();
  
  function moveX() {

    TweenLite.to(point, random(2, 4), {
      x: random(minX, maxX),
      delay: random(0.5),
      onComplete: moveX
    });
  }
  
  function moveY() {

    TweenLite.to(point, random(2, 4), {
      y: random(minY, maxY),
      delay: random(0.5),
      onComplete: moveY
    });
  } 
}

function random(min, max) {
  if (max == null) { max = min; min = 0; }
  if (min > max) { var tmp = min; min = max; max = tmp; }
  return min + (max - min) * Math.random();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that by adding an empty array to the polygon i.e

```
const polygon = draw.polygon([]).node
```

it removes the default {x:0,y:0} object. Dont ask me why :)

Comment: Because if you pass nothing to the polygon method, it will use a default point of `0,0`. These functions are not really meant to be called without any input